# ejabberd.yml configure for strophe register a new user

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe.js

I mount a server ejabberd 18.03 and cliente from this link:
https://gist.github.com/developerworks/317ccf6eb2d3060610f8
BOSH conexion = http://localhost:5280/http-bind

my error in console it is :

The Server does not support In-Band Registration

Ejabberd.yml configuraction

port: 5280

```
ip: "::"

module: ejabberd_http

request_handlers:

  "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws

  "/bosh": mod_bosh

  "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth

  "/api": mod_http_api



http_bind: true

register: true

captcha: false
```

auth_method: internal

#### '   ACCESS CONTROL LISTS

admin:

```
user:

  - "admin@localhot"
```

local:

```
user_regexp: ""
```

loopback:

```
ip:

  - "127.0.0.0/8"

  - "::1/128"

  - "::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128"
```

#### '  SHAPER RULES

max_user_sessions: 10

max_user_offline_messages:

```
- 5000: admin

- 100
```

c2s_shaper:

```
- none: admin

- normal
```

#### '  ACCESS RULES

local:
    - allow: local
c2s:
    - deny: blocked
    - allow

register:
    - allow: trusted_network

trusted_network:

```
- allow: all
```

#### '  MODULES

mod_register:

```
##
## Protect In-Band account registrations with CAPTCHA.
##
##   captcha_protected: true
##
## Set the minimum informational entropy for passwords.
##
##   password_strength: 32
##
## After successful registration, the user receives
## a message with this subject and body.
##

welcome_message:

  subject: "Welcome!"

  body: |-

    Hi.

    Welcome to this XMPP server.

##
## When a user registers, send a notification to
## these XMPP accounts.
##
registration_watchers:

  - "admin1@example.org"

##
## Only clients in the server machine can register accounts
##

ip_access: trusted_network
##
## Local c2s or remote s2s users cannot register accounts
##

access_from: register

access: register
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
  register:
    - allow: trusted_network
```

put

```
  register:
    - allow: all
```

Comment: how solved this error man <iq type='error' from='shakespeare.lit' to='bill@shakespeare.lit/globe' id='unreg1'>
  <error code='400' type='modify'>
    <bad-request xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
  </error>
</iq>